# How to send Div Tag content via email using php form?

Tags: php, javascript, email

I have a div that contains some order info from the online store I'm working on.
I'm interested is there a way to send that content via php email form?

This is the email script I'm using:
Obviously, the $message variable is what bugs me.

```
<?php
                            if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
                                $to = "slavishaofficial@gmail.com";
                                $subject = "Ovo je vasa porudzbina";
                                $email = 'viroposetilac@gmail.com';
                                $message = ???div content???;
                                $headers = "From: $email";
                                $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
                                if ($sent) {
                                    echo "<script>alert('Uspesno ste prosledili porudzbinu na mail')</script>";
                                } else {
                                    echo "<script>alert('Doslo je do problema prilikom slanja porudzbine')</script>";
                                }
                            }

                            ?>
```

Comment: Why not create a form to send the email? Can you post your html? Using jQuery ajax/post functions would probably help.

Comment: whoa there -steady on! "php" "email" "form" deals with several different technologies and physical systems, and you're not very clear what the sequence of events are. Normally it's: HTML form on client side - posting to php server side script (either vanilla form or ajax) resulting in php script to send the response by email in plain text or HTML format. There is no such thing as a "php email form" What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

you cannot get div content directly from php just like that.
you can send from your form with javascript

```
<div id="content">My Content</div>
<form action="/" method="post" onsubmit="this.divcontent.value = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;">
    <input type="hidden" name="divcontent" id="divcontent" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

$message would contain the $_POST['message'] of the div

like

$message = $_POST['message'];

Answer (score 0):

you can encode it first...

```
$str=htmlspecialchars("<div>testing the div</div>", ENT_QUOTES);

$message = $str;
```

then when you need to read ur message decode it and use the following code...

```
$message =htmlspecialchars_decode($orignal_msg_body);
```